# Failed to replicate Bokeh slider.py inside QT

Tags: slider, bokeh

So I figured that the slider function in Bokeh would be useful for my project and I had a look at the example in the official website: http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/slider.html#slider-py

I copied the code exactly as it showed on the website. It ran perfectly fine, and created an identical graph. The only problem was that the slider widget didn't actually do anything. The graph stayed exactly the same, unlike the one that is shown on the webpage.

I am using Jupyter QtConsole. Does anyone has any idea what went wrong? Your effort will be very much appreciated.

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729057/displaying-bokeh-crossfilter-example/44734968#44734968. If you want interactive python callbacks to work in a notebook, you can try this example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064031/bokeh-widget-slicing-data/44158391#44158391

Comment: Please see this answer regarding Bokeh and QWebView, which is not officially supported https://stackoverflow.com/a/39562521/3406693